# c++ cannot convert parameter

Tags: c++, c2664

I am trying to insert rectangle objects to a tree. This is the implementation of insert function.

```
void TwoDimTree::insertNewNode(Rectangle dataIn)
{
insertNewRectangleUtility((&tree), dataIn); 
}


void TwoDimTree::insertNewRectangleUtility(TwoDimTree** temp, Rectangle dataIn)
{
//code here...

}
```

Compiler gives error C2664(cannot convert parameter 2 from Rectangle to Rectangle) in third line:

```
 insertNewRectangleUtility((&tree), dataIn);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you copy pasted this code, or may your actual code contain a typo? Is the type `Rectangle` visible at this point in code?

Comment: What is the **exact** compiler error?  Which compiler?  Which platform?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd.aspx

Comment: Oh and another rather important question: Is this the first error reported by the compiler?

Comment: Please post definition of Rectangle.  Is the copy constructor `private` or `protected`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error message, I would bet on an `explicit`, private, or deleted copy constructor. Mostly likely, the copy constructor is explicit in which case you can copy `Rectangle` explicitly but not implicitly like when passing objects of type `Rectangle` as argument or when returning them from functions. Since you haven't posted the definition of the class `Rectangle` I can't tell for sure, though.